# Fetch Email from IMAP Server Without Inline Attachments - PHP

Tags: php, email, imap

I am working for a support application that fetches emails from an IMAP Server. I have followed this tutorial, http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap and it works. The only problem I have with the tutorial is when the email contains an inline attachment. The message displays base64 encoded strings, which I don't want to be included as I only want to deal with the actual content of the email (text stating the support problem to be addressed).

I have looked in the PHP Manual about IMAP (http://www.php.net/imap) and can't find any resources regarding this.

Is there anyway to fetch an email without the inline files attached to it?

Thanks

Comment: In a very simplified view of the full MIME repertoire, you probably want to fetch the first (or possibly second) body part of a multipart message. Though that might still be base64-encoded, even if the content type is just `text/plain`.

Comment: As an aside, I don't think it matters whether the content disposition is `inline` or not.